# How to change text color of hidden <option>?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-select

I want to change the text color of a hidden option.
The hidden option should be shown as a placeholder text not a selectable option and the placeholder should not shown as element in the select. It should be as shown in the example below. Placeholder text in red and 2 elements to select.
I tried to put the style directly on the element, but that didn't work either.

With this HTML / CSS I was expecting that the text of the "placeholder"-option is red.

```css
select option[hidden] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="" hidden selected style="color: red;">Numbers</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why are you setting an option you actually want to _see_, to `hidden`?

Comment: @CBroe thanks for asking. I would like to display "Numbers" as a placeholder-text and not as a selectable option

Comment: @Justinas I would like to have the placeholder not displayed as an option in the select. Therefore also the hidden attribute.

Comment: The second-highest scoring answer on the target question shows how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) element is not visible, so you can not tell if it's actually changing color.

Maybe you want to change color of `<select>` shown value?

```css
select:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select required>
  <option value="" disabled selected style="color: red;">Numbers</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I would like to display "Numbers" as a placeholder-text and not as a selectable option.

Comment: _"and not as a selectable option"_ - with `disabled`, it won't be _selectable_.

Comment: @creep3007 Check updated

Comment: @CBroe I know, but I won't see this element if I open the select-Box, as seen in my example.